# Black page with Ubuntu logo, x does not start

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg

I have an ASUS laptop with NVidia Geforce GT 220M 1GB
running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

All the drivers are up to date, and Iupdated My Nvidia card 2 weeks ago
and there was no problem with graphics.

Suddenly 1 week ago, when I started Ubuntu from GRUB menu, I saw the purple screeb for 0.25 second, and was stuck at this screen:

[image]

I can use `startx` but Wifi is unavailable and only a few basic programs work. I tried repairing from GRUB menu but no use, and going back to a previous version didn't help.

Today I found this when I tried to start Ubuntu

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ab ... tty1
Username login : * starting mount network filesystems
*stopping mountnetwork systems
```

I accessed the command line and wrote :

```
sudo startx
```

It asked me for Username and password then a black screen, after that

```
 .
..
..
..
..
..
.

xinit : giving up
xinit : unable to communicate to X server no such file on directly 
xinit : Server Error
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But I noticed that it showed in the end of the upgrade that there is not space enough for the last upgrades.

update 3/9/2013

When I started Ubuntu today It showed me this screen for less the none second

[image]

Written under It `BETA DRIVER` In red

Any Ideas?

Comment: Harry - your screen examples are confusing - you mentioned that you have installed 12.04 but one screenshot has ubuntu 11.04, another says ubuntu 20.04 (typo?).  You also mentioned you ran out of space - this is never a good sign.  Can you confirm this i.e. boot into recovery mode and type `df -k` - what is the output?

Comment: NO NO, I didn’t say that is a screen shot it is what I found on google, my version is 12.04 and unfortunately I upgraded to 13.04 LTS, I tried my best but no one knew the solution, and I have work to do, excuse me for not explaining the Picture clearly but I was focusing on finding the solution not the Photo

Comment: as for the Space you I only had like 100 M out of 40 G so yes I confirm, thanks for you effort man I will always put that In mind

Comment: oh dear! looks like then you have either an alpha/beta issue with 13.04 - or because of the lack of space - the upgrade has gone wrong during the upgrade.  13.04 is not an LTS release - its is still in development.  I've no idea how you managed to install 13.04 from 12.04 - it isnt normally possible - you have to install 12.10 first. Best advice is to boot with a live CD, backup your data and reinstall from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to recover your system should be fix the space problem and repair potentially broken packages.

Please follow this little guidance:

1. boot to recovery mode or use arescue cd
2. open a shell
3. set an environment variable `rootPartition` for later use. It should contain the device holding the root partition of your damaged installation
4. Run the following command. Please review if before and check that
   all assumptions are correct, e.g. the ext4 file system. (It is copied
   from my [notepad](http://www.computer42.org/xwiki-static/exported/DevNotes/xwiki.DevNotes.Rescue%20Tasks.html#Hmountinganexistinginstallationchroot).)

   ```
   rootPartition="$(echo /dev/mapper/*-root)" 
   mkdir /target
   mount ${rootPartition} /target

   # preserve network resolution
   cat /etc/resolv.conf  >/target/etc/resolv.conf 

   # special file systems 
   mount -o bind /dev /target/dev
   mount -o bind /sys /target/sys
   mount -t proc none /target/proc

   # for grub, update-initramfs, ...
   # * use correct mount table (existing is not in sync!)
   # * prepend the correct view of the root partition (needed for update-initramfs)
   { echo ${rootPartition} / ext4 rw 0 0
     cat  /proc/mounts 
   } > /target/etc/mtab # for grub reinstallation

   # switch 
   chroot /target /bin/bash
   ```
5. Now you are in your broken installation. You may try to mount additional partitions like `/usr/` if needed.
6. Inspect your running low of diskspace problem and do the right steps to solve it. If you need assistance here, I`m sure you may find already the required hints on *askubuntu*.
7. Don't forget to ensure that the installation is in a sane state:

   - `dpkg --configure -a`
   - `apt-get update`
   - `apt-get install -f`
8. Reinstall the *nvidia drivers* packages

   1. ensure to remove the current drivers `dpkg --purge --force-depends "nvidia*`
   2. install again: `apt-get install -f nvidia-current`

On the first image is ubuntu **11.04** shown.
So you should also ensure that your system is really upgraded to 12.04.

- Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that all references to *natty* are removed and the repositories for *precise* are declared.
- Enforce an upgrade: `apt-get dist-upgrade`

With a little bit luck you can reboot back to a running installation.